# Adding a Table View Cell to a Table View within a View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a subclass of `UIView` (`MyView`) that I've hooked up to a NIB file.

```
class MyView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setup()
    }

    let nibName = "MyView"

    private func setup() {

        let bundle = Bundle.init(for: type(of: self))
        bundle.loadNibNamed(nibName, owner: self, options: nil)

        contentView.frame = self.bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        self.addSubview(contentView)
    }

}
```

This view is simple; containing only one `UITableView` (or `tableView`). However, I want to add a `UITableViewCell` with a `UILabel` to `tableView` but the storyboard is not letting me do this.

I understand that `MyView` is not a view controller and therefore **should not** (if following an MVC pattern) implement the various table view data source / delate methods, but, still, why can I not add this table view cell to the table view within this custom view?

My aim was to then have some `UIViewController` subclass that has an instance of `MyView`, i.e.

```
var myView = MyView(),
```

which it then controls the datasource and delegate methods for, i.e.

```
myView.tableView.dataSource = self.
```

Finally, I've attached a screenshot showing that I am unable to add this table view cell to the table view.

[image]

Comment: _I understand that MyView is not a view controller and therefore cannot implement the various table view data source / delate methods_ - why not?

Comment: "I understand that MyView is not a view controller and therefore cannot implement the various table view data source / delate methods" this is *incorrect*, you could `class MyView: UIView, UITableViewDataSoruce {...}` and it should works fine...

Comment: Please see the edit in bold. I want the view and the controller separated to follow the MVC design pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add prototype cells to table views in xib files - only in storyboards.

You *can* create your table view in one xib, and your table view cell in another xib, if you want.

Or, you can create a second storyboard that would contain a table view *and* it would support cell prototypes.